# C# MVC Requerying a database on Post Back from Ajax call or Returning the posted model

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc, post

**Background**

I have a view that is divided in many little forms with the help of `Partial Views` and `Editor Templates`. Each form has a save button, and when a user submits one of the forms a loader.gif is shown for that section until the ajax call is done. Right now, I am just returning the partial view based on the model that was posted. If there is a problem with the data they are posting, my validation class will return a message or the application will throw an exception.

**Problem**

One problem I could see is if my application thinks the data was saved (e.g. no exception and no validation error), but for some reason the clients data was not mapped correctly to the entities, services, database etc (I do have unit tests in place). If i am returning the model that was given to me, the client will not see that the change failed because the new value will be in the view. If i re-queried the database and repopulated the model, the user would see a success message in the view, but the data would revert back to before the save. The requerying does add extra overhead and logic to the action method, but is it necessary? Just wanted to know what others do or if I am thinking too much about this. Thanks.

```
// this is the view that other actions will call because they are all the same on the controller
// only use TQueryParam if I am requerying
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public PartialViewResult Edit<TModel, TCommandParam, TQueryParam>(TModel model, string viewName, IViewModelEnricher<TModel> enricher = null) where TCommandParam : ICommandParam
{   
  // fill in necessary properties such as select lists
  if (enricher != null)
    enricher.Enrich(model);

  if (ModelState.IsValid)
  {
    var cmdParam = Mapper.Map<TModel, TCommandParam>(model);

    foreach (var error in _dispatcher.Validate(cmdParam))
      ModelState.AddModelError(error.MemberName, error.Message);

    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
      _dispatcher.Dispatch(cmdParam);
      TempData["Saved"] = "Your data was saved successfully!";

      // TODO: do i requery database for the model and make this method a little more complicated?
      //var result = _dispatcher.Dispatch<TQueryParam>(new GetOperationById(model.Id));
      //model = Mapper.Map<TQueryParam, TModel>(result);
    }
  }

  return PartialView(viewName, model);
}
```

Comment: "if my application thinks the data was saved (e.g. no exception and no validation error), but for some reason the clients data was not mapped correctly to the entities"... Why do you think that may happen? If there's a possibility of that happening, then there should be something wrong with your error handling logic.

Comment: i tend to over-analyze things (probably because of my work prior to programming), so i try to think of all possible faults in the code. Would you be fine with just passing the model back?

Comment: Where in your code is error handling being done? The only thing that may lead to your data not being saved is an exception (assuming you don't believe in miracles or supernatural powers :D). So, as longs as you are doing proper exception handling (e.g. by using a try-catch block), you'll be ok. I don't see that in your Action, so is that being done somewhere else (like in a custom HanldeErrorAttribute)?

Comment: I am handling only a few exceptions in my application layer, but those are okay to catch and continue with. If an exception occurs I want it to bubble up to the web project and trigger `ELMAH`, which would fire the `.failed` on ajax

Comment: But are you capturing the base Exception class as well (to cover all exceptions)? From the code you posted here, it's not clear what you are doing. What does your Action return in case of an exception or in case the Model is not valid?

Comment: The action always returns the partial view with the model. If the model is not valid the appropriate error messages are added to the model and the second `ModelState.IsValid` will fail. If an exception occurs that I do not handle in any of the layers, I do nothing and the `.fail`. fires on `ajax` and the user gets a message that something failed. Their changes are still preserved because the view does not change and i can review the error in my `ELMAH` log

Comment: Then, in case of the error, I would make the Action return a different model (like an empty one), so the user know that the data has not been saved.

Comment: The only downside to that is the users data would be lost unless i saved it in a session variable. Right now I have an alert box and `span` with an error message.

Comment: Well, then, it's just the matter of making sure the user knows the data has not been updated (which I think you are already doing).

Comment: I appreciate the input, thank you!